# upserting items to a ListField in MongoEngine

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have to following collection with me

```
class SkillCluster(DynamicDocument):
    Name = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    SubClusters = ListField(StringField())
    ModifiedDate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['Name'],
        'index_background': True,
        'collection': 'SkillCluster',
        'db_alias': resume_db_alias_name
    }
```

I have written a function to get the document from above collection like this -

```
def get_cluster(cluster_name, sub_cluster_name):
    # check if a document exists with name as cluster_name and sub_cluster_name is present in SubClusters List 
    cluster_set = SkillCluster.objects(Name=cluster_name, SubClusters__contains=sub_cluster_name)
    if cluster_set:
        return cluster_set[0]
    else:
        # Check if document exists with Name as cluster_name, if yes then add sub_cluster_name in SubClusters list else create the document.
        cluster_set = SkillCluster.objects(Name=cluster_name)
        if cluster_set:
            cluster = cluster_set[0].update(add_to_set__SubClusters=sub_cluster_name, ModifiedDate=datetime.utcnow())
        else:
            data_dict = {"ModifiedDate": datetime.utcnow(), "SubClusters": [sub_cluster_name]}
            cluster = SkillCluster.objects(Name=cluster_name).modify(upsert=True, new=True, **data_dict)
        return cluster
```

Is there a way to club the last if-else condition into one single query, like creating the document if document with `cluster_name` doesn't exists else add the `sub_cluster_name` to the `SubClusters` list in the document (kind of upsert query)